# heroku pgbackups:restore not working on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

For some reason heroku pgbackups:restore won't work on my rails app,

I'm creating my dumpfile using the command:

```
pg_dump -F c -v -U john -h localhost project_development > -f dumpfile.dump
```

I then upload it to dropbox, as the heroku documentation says it needs to be needs to uploaded somewhere with an HTTP-accessible URL. After I've uploaded the file to dropbox, I then run the command

```
heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/JgHkmg0iv8vIMKWqlN6medJqjClPeWYl2AQqJWV8IeEiujnfYvPdtvq7xh26dvCQ'
```

the output of which is

```
Retrieving... done
Restoring... done
```

HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL is my database url and the line in the single quotes is a raw version of my dumpfile(the dropbox documentation showed how to turn the dl file into a raw file).

But whenever go to my apps homepage I get an error, I can see from running `heroku logs` that the error is a database error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "listings" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings"   ORDER BY listings.pri..
```

Also, when I run `heroku pg:info` I can see that nothing has actually been inserted into the database

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 2/20
PG Version:  9.3.4
Created:     2014-10-21 15:24 UTC
Data Size:   7.0 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

Can anyone tell me why my database isn't being updated? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `--no-acl --no-owner` to the pg_dump command.

Comment: tried, but my pg_dump command failed because of too many command line args, I don't think pg_dump is the problem though because I can look at the dumpfile and see that it has been correctly made, it's the loading that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Make sure those args are before the name of your database. Like: `pg_dump -F c -v -U --no-acl --no-owner john -h localhost project_development > -f dumpfile.dump`

Comment: Hmm, still no joy, exact console output it this
`pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "project_development")
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on a blank hobby dev database with heroku. You don't need to include the the no-owner and no-acl options (`-x -O`) but it's considered good practice since those alter statements will fail.

The problem with your dump command is the stray `>`

```
pg_dump -F c -v -O -x -U john -h localhost project_development -f dumpfile.dump
```

Upload the resulting file to dropbox or s3 and try the restore again. If there are errors you can run

```
heroku logs -n 100 --ps pgbackups
```

To see the log output from the pg_restore command.

Comment: aha! so `pg_dump` command seems to work fine either way, but the `heroku logs -n 100 --ps pgbackups` command worked well! I could see a lot of `Invalid dump format: /tmp/QeLqxGAVkX/dumpfile.dump: HTML document text` in the logs, and it was because whenever heroku tried to access my link, it expired, so I was only ever access dropbox's 404 page ... but I found a second way of creating the link that doesn't expire `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/l0qb4vjadliiffc/dumpfile.dump` by simply going to the file and changing the www.dropbox in the url to dl.dropboxusercontent! Thanks!